# Affine Function Proofs

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *affine* if $f(x+y-z) = f(x)+f(y)-f(z)$ for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$.  A function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *additive* if $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

(1) Assume $f$ is an affine function and $m$ is a real number. Define $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $g(x) = f(x)-[mx+f(0)]$. Show that $g$ is an additive function.

(2) Let $m = f(1) -f(0)$ and show that the function defined in item (1) has the property that $g(x+1)=g(x)$.

(3) Suppose $f$ is affine and bounded on $[0,1]$, and $g$ is defined by $g(x) = f(x)-[mx+b]$ where $m = f(1) -f(0)$ and $b=f(0)$. Show that $g$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

(4) Show that any bounded, additive function must be the zero function.

(5) Show that if $f$ is affine and continuous, there are real numbers $m$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=mx+b$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (1) and (2) are very straightforward and I already know how to do them. However, (3) (4) and (5) are the ones I could really use some help on. Also, you can use the things that have been proved in the previous proofs to prove the things in the later proofs. I hope that makes sense. Anyway, thank you all soooo much for your help in advance.

Comment: are the square brackets in #3 just parens?

Comment: the square brackets around [0,1] mean that the interval is closed. The square brackets around the [mx+b] i believe could be replaced by parens.

Comment: I have no idea... pay no attention to that. You were a great help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. $g(x) = f(x) - (mx + b) = f(x) - xf(1) + (x-1)f(0)$. But $|f(x)| \leq M$ on for all $x$ on $(0, 1)$ for some $M$ since $f$ is bounded.

$|f(x) - xf(1) + (x-1)f(0)|<|M| +|M| + |M|= 3M$

by the triangle inequality, and using the fact that $1>x$ and $1>(x-1)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. It's not a very good estimate, but we don't need it to be good, we just need it to work. That shows that **IF** $f$ is bounded on $[0, 1]$, then $g(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

4. Prove by induction that $f(m) = f(1 +... + 1) = f(1) + ... + f(1) = mf(1)$. If $|f(1)| > 0$ then...
5. My hint for 5 may have been misleading. It's actually much easier because we can use the rest of the problem. I'll let you fill in the gaps:

$f$ is affine and continuous. Since it's continuous, it's bounded on the set $[0, 1]$. Let $g(x) = f(x) - (mx + b)$ as defined in part (3). $g$ is bounded by part (3) and additive by part (1). Thus, g must be the zero function by part (4). So, $f(x) = mx + b$.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, there is a way to use induction on the reals, but you don't need it here. If you're interested, See [Pete Clark's notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/realinduction.pdf). For 4, you can just use normal (positive integer) induction. Like, $f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1) + f(1) = 2f(1)$ And so on, which is good enough. For example, if I want to find some number $m$ so that $f(m) > N$ for any positive $N$, then we can just say $f(m) > n \implies mf(1) > N \implies m > \frac{N}{f(1)}$.

Comment: for (3), when $x\notin [0,1]$, since $f$ is affine, you can break up the f(x) into f(1+1+...+1) x times. Thus, f(1+1+1...+1) = f(1)+f(1)+....+f(1) x times. Could you conclude that since f(1) is bounded, f(x) is also bounded? Since every real number can be broken up into 1's and decimals?

Comment: for (4), if $0<|f(1)|<1$, as $m$ gets big, wouldn't $m$$f(1)$  approach zero? Then something other than the zero function would still be bounded?

Comment: I added some more for #3. As for #4, why would $mf(1)$ approach zero? We can make $m$ as big as we want, and $f(1)$ is a fixed constant. Pretend $f(1) = 1/2$. Then $f(2) = 2(1/2)$, $f(4)= 4(1/2)$...

Comment: yes you're totally right. For some reason i thought f(1) was approaching 0 as m got bigger... [facepalm]

Comment: been there done that :)

Comment: You've been a great help so far and I really appreciate it. I have another question about (4) though. I understand that if f(1)>0 then f(m) will be unbounded, but how do you prove by induction for a function on the Reals? I thought one would use induction for the natural numbers?

Comment: Also for (5) i know that if you let $\delta = \dfrac{\varepsilon} {|m|}$, it shows f is continuous for all real numbers $x_0$. However, i'm not sure how to show that $m$ and $b$ exist. Does the fact that $\delta$ is a function of $m$ prove that $m$ exists? But then what about $b$?

Comment: I've updated it again. Let me know if you have any more questions!